# Mysql 5.6 installation on user given path in linux

Tags: linux, mysql

I am trying to install mysql 5.6 (from an RPM) on RHEL 6.4 in the user desired location, but it is installing in /usr/bin location. Is there any way to change the location to install mysql?

Comment: What specific steps are you taking to install the software? (Yes, it matters.)

Comment: using rpm i am installing the mysql....hope i answered your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--relocate` switch to `rpm` to install into an alternate directory hierarchy.

For example, consider `rpm --install --relocate /=/home/kayle/mysql mysql-5.6.rpm` which should install everything under /home/kayle/mysql rather than under /. Hence, anything that would have gone into /etc goes into /home/kayle/mysql/etc, files normally installed into /usr/bin go into /home/kayle/mysql/usr/bin, and so on. You can repeat --relocate an arbitrary number of times if you want finer control over which directory paths are rewritten to where; see the `rpm` man page.

*This may or may not work out of the box* depending on what specific paths are needed in various configuration files, helper scripts etc., but it *should* get you started by at least *installing* the files in your desired location.

*If the RPM isn't relocatable* you can always (well, mostly always) download the source code and build the software yourself, configuring it with a prefix of your choosing. (It's *usually* - read, when GNU Autoconf is used - done with a `./configure --prefix=/home/kayle/mysql` step or parameter, but you'd need to check the documentation for the specific software package to be sure.) It won't get tracked by the system's package manager, but depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish that might not be a huge deal.

Comment: but mysql rpm's are not relocatable... "error: package MySQL-server is not relocatable"

Comment: Then I don't think you can do it, at least not with standard system facilities. Depending on how badly you want to do it, you could of course manually unpack the RPM and configure the software.